# PHP replace digits with question marks

Tags: php

If I have a string such as a number, how to replace it with question marks in PHP? I've dug around and can't seem to find an answer to this. I believe a regular expression can handle it but not any good with those!

Example:

5,432.00
becomes
?,???.??

Comment: And what have you tried? Do you expect us to write this for you? Because that is not really the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**`preg_replace`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) which performs a regular expression search and replace, like the below sample:

```
<?php
$str = "5,432.00";
$result = preg_replace('/\d/', '?', $str);
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
?,???.??
```

[**Live DEMO**](https://eval.in/243352)

`\d` means any digit, you could use `[0-9]` instead as well.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't try but it should work.

```
$variable = preg_replace('/(\d)/', '?', $variable);
```

For more information : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

you could use preg_replace and a regular expression so it replace only numbers, like this:

```
$string = '1234556abcd';
$replaced = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '?', $string);
echo $replaced;
```

The result should look like this:
??????abcd